# How to created multiple instances of a nested attribute in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

Essentially I want to populate multiple instances of the same nested attribute object using a single form.  Is this possible?

I have:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childs
  acceptes_nested_attributes_for :childs
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

and then the view for parents/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @parent, url: parents_path(@parent), method: :post do |f| %>
  // basic fields for parent
  <%= f.fields_for :child do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

that works fine, but if I want to do something like:

```
<%= form_for @parent, url: parents_path(@parent), method: :post do |f| %>
  // basic fields for parent
  <%= f.fields_for :child do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.title %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :child do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

it only populates the params with the last fields_for entry.  What is the proper way to create a form that allows for instantiation of multiple instances of a nested attribute?

Answer (score -1):

A better way to do this would be in your controller action:

```
def new
  @parent = Parent.find(1)

  # Build 2 children
  2.times do 
    @parent.children.build
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= form_for @parent, url: parents_path(@parent), method: :post do |f| %>
  // basic fields for parent
  <%= f.fields_for :children do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update:**

Not really answer to the question but suggesting a few changes based on Rails convention.  Since `"child".pluralize` returns children, I think the model should be updated to use `has_many :children` so the class name would be resolved properly `"child".pluralize.classify`.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  acceptes_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

And corresponding change in the view:

```
<%= form_for @parent, url: parents_path(@parent), method: :post do |f| %>
  // basic fields for parent
  <%= f.fields_for :children do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but was hoping for some way to provide this functionality through raw construction of the form.  That way the user can decide how many instances of child they want to create.

Comment: @DanielNill, How would the user decide?  How will you handle that?  One way I've done similar design is using ajax where an user would, say, click an "Add" button which adds a new `child` record in the view.  Can you explain it a little more what type of design you are expecting to implement?

Comment: The user would describe by using essentially what you describe, but there should be no need to make an ajax call.  Unless you are editing an existing parent there should be no need to build it's children before hand, other than for convention of what the form expects.  It would be far easier to just append new elements to the form at the user's request and then build the attributes hash in the create method of the controller.  I was just hoping there was a rails convention to get around this.  Sounds like there is not. :(

Comment: @DanielNill, if you haven't already seen this, take a look at this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2.  It might be related!

Comment: thanks for the update, but child and parent are just placeholders for the actual model names i'm working with.